# Tried accessing nonexisting field (fql) on node type (User)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

FQL requests fail since wednesday. I have no clue why since FQL is supposed to be deprecated only at the end of April.

Basically, here is the type of requests that worked until wednesday :

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/89240001803405/fql?access_token=<access_code>&q=select+is_published%2C+talking_about_count%2C+access_token%2C+description%2C+emails%2C+fan_count%2C+general_info%2C+location%2C+page_url%2C+pic_square%2C+username%2C+page_id%2Cname+from+page+WHERE+page_id+IN+%28SELECT+page_id+FROM+page_admin+where+uid+%3D+89240001803405%29
```

And here is the current response :

```
{
  "error": {
  "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (fql) on node type (User)",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 100
  }
}
```

Any idea how I can fix this before I migrate de non FQL ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the user(?) id doing in there? As far as I know, FQL calls have always been of the form `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=…`

Comment: Thank you. It must have been accepted until wednesday. I just removed it and it's now OK. I cannot close this question since you commented it and did not answer it apparently. If you add an answer, I'll close this question and will tag your answer as the solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user id you have in there before the `fql` part is wrong, as far as I know. If that has worked before, then rather by accident, I guess.

FQL calls via API endpoint should be of the form `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=…` – the identifier `fql` as first path segment, follow by parameters such as `q` for the query, the access token and what else might be appropriate.

Specifying the user id first doesn’t make sense, because what data you want to select you define inside the query itself.

Comment: **FQL is deprecated as of August 8, 2016** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/